# How can I copy row from AngularJS ng-grid to clients clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, clipboard, ng-grid

I would like to give users the ability to copy a row or elements of a row of ng-grid (AngularJS) to their clipboard.  dataTables for JQuery has that option.  How do I do something similar in ng-grid?